# Запуск независимо от Visual Studio

Tags: c#

Можно ли сделать из проекта на C# отдельную программу, которую можно будет запускать независимо от visual studio? Чтобы запускать на компьютерах без visual studio.

Comment: @Vezd, А разве бывает по другому?

Comment: Лишь бы стоял .NET Framework...

Comment: А какие файлы надо для этого копировать из проекта?

Comment: В вашем случае, только полученный при компиляции экзешник.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы запустили VS, открыли проект, то запустите его (F5) после чего можете его закрыть, далее идём в папку, где хранятся ваши проекты(по умолчанию это `C:\Documents and Settings\User\Мои документы\Visual Studio 2010\Projects`) Там найдите директорию с вашим проектом, зайдите в него, потом  `bin\Debug\Название проекта.exe` только него, не надо копировать всё папку.

Comment: У меня к проекту еще ddl библиотека подключена. Если я беру только один exe файл с названием проекта, то при использовании функции, которые связаны с библиотекой ddl  появляется ошибка. Значит надо еще и эти ddl брать?

Comment: Ну в таком случае, скопируйте ещё и библиотеку.

Answer (score 4):

Когда запускаете проект в VS, то происходит компиляция программы. В папке проекта найдите папку bin, далее Debug или Release в зависимости от конфигурации проекта.  Или я вопроса не понял?

Comment: Всю папку Debug брать?